# Error "Interactive" No instance for (Show ((Int, Int) -> String)) - Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm in the middle of the way of a backtracking function. This is what i've done so far, it was working, then i added an extra value and now GHCi is printing an error. I'm still new to this language and i don't know how to fix this. Help!

```
backtracking :: [[Int]] -> (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) -> String --montapuercos (posActual, vida)
backtracking matriz montapuercos memory | checkMove (-1,0) montapuercos memory matriz = "Norte "++(backtracking matriz (-1+(fst montapuercos),(snd montapuercos)) montapuercos)
                                            | checkMove (0,1) montapuercos memory matriz = "Este "++(backtracking matriz (fst montapuercos,(snd montapuercos)+1) montapuercos)
                                            | checkMove (1,0) montapuercos memory matriz = "Sur "++(backtracking matriz (fst montapuercos+1,(snd montapuercos)) montapuercos)
                                            | checkMove (0,-1) montapuercos memory matriz = "Oeste "++(backtracking matriz (fst montapuercos,(snd montapuercos)-1) montapuercos)
                                            | montapuercos == (length matriz,length(head matriz)) = " Llegué a la salida"

checkMove :: (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int)  -> (Int,Int) -> [[Int]] -> Bool
checkMove (mx,my) (pA1,pA2) (mem1,mem2) matriz  | ( (pA1+mx) >= 0 && (pA1+mx) < length matriz ) &&
                                                ( (pA2+my) >= 0 && (pA2+my) < length (head matriz) ) && 
                                                ( (pA1+mx) /= mem1 && (pA2+my) /= mem2 ) = True                                             
                                                | otherwise = False
```

This is the error i get

```
<interactive>:105:1:
    No instance for (Show ((Int, Int) -> String))
      arising from a use of ‘print’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You typed, in GHCi, `print it`.  The `it` you just tried to print is a function and can not be shown. If you would like you may evaluate the function by providing it with an argument of type `(Int,Int)` then print the result.

Comment: I've never typed such thing! This is what i'm passing to GHCi: 
    backtracking [[18,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,6]] (0,0)

Comment: Same concept, though the error message could be improved in this case.  Your `backtracking` function takes 3 arguments but you have provided only 2.

Comment: Omg i'm so dumb! Thank you, Thomas.! Now i've learned how to understand new kind of console errors.

Comment: To expand on that: the concept is the same because providing fewer arguments is legal - it is just partial application.  You thus have a result that is a function from `missing argument` to `result type`.  And, as stated above, functions can't be printed in a meaningful manner.

Comment: That's also true, professor taught me that. Although is not a concept that i've mastered yet (about partial application)!

Comment: Are you using an old GHC version, perhaps? GHCi here clearly suggests the solution using "(maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)" in the middle of the error message.

Comment: Yes, might be that. Since i'm on 32 bits computer, newer versions are only available for 64 bits architectures

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson `print it` is a thing ghci implicitly does. Mentioning that to new haskellers as though they'd typed it themselves is just confusing.

Comment: @amalloy Yes, I've just internalized that `print it` is not just implicit, but that abstraction leaks through to the error message as shown above. I agree exposing it to the user as though they typed it themselves is confusing and we should patch GHC.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused because i increased the amount of parameters but forgot to do add it when i was calling the function, and that's why i was getting the error:

```
backtracking [[18,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,6]] (0,0)
```

but i declared it this way:

```
backtracking :: [[Int]] -> (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) -> String
```

It's useful for newbies in Haskell like me to understand why errors are showing.Thanks to @Thomas M. DuBuisson for helping me out. Let's keep rocking!